# How can I migrate this template snippet from Thymeleaf 2.1.4 to Thymeleaf 3.0?

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a template like this:

```
<table th:with="isEven=false">
        <tr th:if="*{foo} != null" class='odd' th:class="${isEven=!isEven}?'even':'odd'">
        foo
        </tr>
        <tr th:if="*{bar} != null" class='odd' th:class="${isEven=!isEven}?'even':'odd'">
        bar
        </tr>
</table>
```

It worked with Thymeleaf 2.1.4 but with 3.0.0 it throws the following exception:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException:
   Exception evaluating OGNL expression: "isEven=!isEven" (template: "foo" - line 10, col 34)

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
   Cannot set values into VariablesMap instances from OGNL Expressions
```

Any idea how to fix this?

**Note:**
This is not a loop so there is no `varStat` object like in

`<tr th:each="prod : ${prods}" th:class="${prodStat.odd}? 'odd'">`

The `<tr>` are generated depending on the `th:if` condition and I'd like to have an even/odd toggle for them.

**Edit**: I opened a [Github issue](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/498) for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thymeleaf 3 does not allow modifying context variables as a lateral effect from OGNL/SpringEL expressions (which in fact is something that was wrongly allowed in 2.1).

But if I'm understanding your code correctly, you should be able to create the flags you need in a `th:with`. Something like this:

```
<table th:with="hasFoo=(*{foo} != null)">
    <tr th:if="${hasFoo}" class='even'>foo</tr>
    <tr th:if="*{bar} != null" class='odd' th:class="${hasFoo}? even : odd">bar</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's not helping much since there are lots and lots of other different variables that follow `foo` and `bar`. It's meant to "print something" if the content isn't null/empty, and do so with alternating "even"/"odd" class in the generated output. I essentially need a `varStat` but without an enclosing loop, something a bit like a "manual" varStat.

Comment: In such case, it seems the most adequate solution would be to create a bean that you include in your context, and which methods you can call from your expressions to return an index (and another method to tell you if it is even or odd). Similar to varStat, but added manually.